# Phrase for there is a lot of a thing

Tags: phrases, expressions

I want to say he invited so many people and the house is (full of man?!)

Rabbits mate very fast and Australia gets (full of rabbits?!)

What is the phrase which use in this cases? Something that is extremely much in numbers?

Comment: You don't want to have to count; change the situation instead. If a collection of count nouns gets really big, its granularity gets smaller and you can treat it as a fluid, like flour or sand, and use verbs like _overflow with_. A house can overflow with people, and Australia with rabbits (metaphorically, of course).

Comment: I have always liked [plethora](http://movies.stackexchange.com/), meaning a superabundance or a glut... a plethora of rabbits, people

Comment: Sounds like your house is _overrun_ with rabbits. Good luck with that.

Comment: There’s a musical group called *Crowded House*...  I’d recommend that for a party. and if there are too many people then it’s *too crowded*... I like @JanusBahsJacquet’s - *overrun* for rabbits.

Comment: How about "inundated" or "to the brim"? In some sense, these expressions give a feel of overwhelming fullness.

Comment: As an aside, @Jim’s comment illustrates an important problem with this question: **is the multitude of these things a good thing or a bad thing?** If the house is filled to the brim with party guests, that may well be a good thing, and you could say the house is _teeming with_ guests. Rabbits in Australia on the other hand are a major pest, which is why we think of Australia as _overrun_ with rabbits. But most words for this will depend on whether the number of things is good or bad.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. I mean in a bad manner and overrun is exactly what i wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some or the words that you would like to use would be

**Inundate,
Deluge,
Plethora,
Cascade** (Because a large number of rabbits are begotten in one go).